# If a DFA can be simulated by a real program, can it be simulated by a TM

Tags: computability, simulation, turing-completeness

In proofs of decidability, we often want to simulate another model of computation by a Turing machine. But if I can simulate a $\mathsf{DFA}$ by, say, a C program, then is there some result which says that the $\mathsf{DFA}$ can be simulated by some $\mathsf{TM}$? Could a program be used in place of a $\mathsf{TM}$ in a proof of decidability?

I know that Java being Turing-complete would mean that it can simulate any $\mathsf{TM}$, so this is sort of the reverse of Turing-completeness I guess.

Comment: Yes, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the same limited view on computation as Turing machines, then yes: typical programming languages are Turing complete and thus (for all we know) equivalent in power to TMs.

A simpler proof presents itself, too: if you look closely enough, finite automata are just Turing machines that don't use their tape.

Keep in mind, though, that Turing machines lack some features of modern real machines/languages: distributed computation (i.e. communication), user interaction, online algorithms and never terminating systems with continuous I/O (e.g. operating systems) are just some examples. If your simulation program uses such features, the simulation may not carry over to TMs.

Comment: Typical programming languages are Turing complete and thus *are* equivalent in power to TMs. Also, distributed computing can be simulated by TMs - A single TM can simulate arbitrarily many other Turing machines (= communication partners) at the same time. It sure gets much slower, but it works. And assuming that a human is also just a computation machine that is Turing complete, even user interaction could be simulated by a TM. That last assumption is of course debatable.

Comment: @Jost: A TM like you describe can simulate *serialisations* of parallel computations, but not the parallelism. For instance, notions of runtime and communication overhead get muddled. Another thing that TMs don't model are streaming/online algorithms, e.g. operating systems. Adding that.

Answer (score 1):

The Church–Turing thesis states that every intuitive model of computation can be simulated by a Turing machine. This is not a theorem, just an informal principle, which holds in your case: every C program can be simulated by a Turing machine. Formally showing this would be tedious, but such facts are commonly assumed.

The fact that C is Turing-complete is in fact *stronger* than what you need: it states that C can be simulated by Turing machines and vice versa.

Comment: I thought the "vice versa" part was implied by something being Turing-equivalent, not Turing-complete. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness#Formal_definitions

Comment: (And thank you for the answer. I've chosen Raphael's, but both of your answers were good.)